# Nested SQL - Distinct Load Left Join in one statement

Tags: sql, nested, left-join, distinct

I wanted to left join two queries:

First:

```
 SELECT TIG_TOL.sName AS Maschine, 
        TIG_TOL.lTolRef, 
        Max(TIG_JOB.tActBegin) AS MaxvontActBegin
 FROM TIG_JOB LEFT JOIN TIG_TOL ON TIG_JOB.lMacRef = TIG_TOL.lTolRef
 WHERE (((TIG_JOB.sState)="Run" Or (TIG_JOB.sState)="Ready"))
 GROUP BY TIG_TOL.sName, TIG_TOL.lTolRef;
```

Second:

```
SELECT TIG_JOB.sName AS Auftrag, 
       TIG_JOB.lJobRef,
       TIG_TOL.sName AS Artikel, 
       TIG_TOL.sDescript AS Artikel_Bezeichnung
FROM (TIG_JOB LEFT JOIN TIG_TOL_BOK ON TIG_JOB.lJobRef = TIG_TOL_BOK.lJobRef)
     LEFT JOIN TIG_TOL ON (TIG_TOL_BOK.lTolRef = TIG_TOL.lTolRef) 
                       AND (TIG_TOL_BOK.lTolTypRef =          TIG_TOL.lTolTypRef)
WHERE (((TIG_TOL.lTolTypRef)=10));
```

Over a left join

```
on First.MaxvontActBegin = Second.TIG_JOB.tActBegin
AND First.TIG_TOL.lTolRef = Second.TIG_JOB.lMacRef
```

Is that possible? In Access Im doing it over two queries, where the second is using the first..

Comment: Have you tried to join these queries? Show us the query you've built and tell us what's going wrong

Comment: I dont really know about what to join as in First and Second im using the same tables. Can I join on given names lice 'as MaxvontActBegin'??

Comment: Is it oracle/mysql/MSSQL? what is the RDBMS are you using

Comment: MS SQL - but should that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I (blindly) added `TIG_JOB.tActBegin` and `TIG_JOB.lMacRef` to the 2nd `SELECT` (hoping they exist) in order to JOIN the two results.

I used `SELECT *` only because you did not specify the column selection.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TIG_TOL.sName AS Maschine, 
        TIG_TOL.lTolRef, 
        Max(TIG_JOB.tActBegin) AS MaxvontActBegin
    FROM TIG_JOB LEFT JOIN TIG_TOL ON TIG_JOB.lMacRef = TIG_TOL.lTolRef
    WHERE (((TIG_JOB.sState)="Run" Or (TIG_JOB.sState)="Ready"))
    GROUP BY TIG_TOL.sName, TIG_TOL.lTolRef
) AS FirstTable
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT TIG_JOB.sName AS Auftrag, 
       TIG_JOB.lJobRef,
       TIG_TOL.sName AS Artikel, 
       TIG_TOL.sDescript AS Artikel_Bezeichnung,
       TIG_JOB.tActBegin,
       TIG_JOB.lMacRef
    FROM (TIG_JOB LEFT JOIN TIG_TOL_BOK ON TIG_JOB.lJobRef = TIG_TOL_BOK.lJobRef)
    LEFT JOIN TIG_TOL ON (TIG_TOL_BOK.lTolRef = TIG_TOL.lTolRef) 
    AND (TIG_TOL_BOK.lTolTypRef = TIG_TOL.lTolTypRef)
    WHERE (((TIG_TOL.lTolTypRef)=10))
) AS SecondTable
ON FirstTable.MaxvontActBegin = SecondTable.tActBegin
AND FirstTable.lTolRef = SecondTable.lMacRef`
```